# Need to disable an array of ctrl keys for my site

Tags: wordpress, ctrl

Especially <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> , which is "mail this page". I'm using wordpress self hosted. So far I've found [this](http://vapus.net/forum/servers-hosting-246/anti-sql-injection-blocking-right-click-your-website-2241/) code, not sure how to implement it or if it's old.

Please no plethora of reasons as to why you find this attempt pointless.

Comment: Ha! This question is pointless :). There are always ways around these kinds of hacks.

Comment: If you want to leave comments, please use the comment facilities under each answer.

Answer (score 1):

Really, shouldn't answer, but:

There's no reason for this, because there's always a very easy way around it. It'll probably take a lot more work than whatever you end up with's worth. If somebody has half of a computer literate mind, they probably can get past this without a problem at all.

Summary:
Don't bother

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that.  See [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) for really good information on the portability of various key events in JavaScript across multiple browsers.  You will see for one that each browser handles/responds to various key events in many different ways.

Also, most of the default browser actions (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>) cannot be canceled if you are capturing key events.  You can still detect some of them and respond, but you can't actually stop the browser from displaying the search dialog or whatever specific action is to be performed by the key combination.

Also, if someone really wants to take your page's HTML/JavaScript code or content, these methods won't stop them.  The disable right click code from the link you referenced can prevent right click, but all someone has to do is disable javascript and it no longer works.

Comment: "most of the default browser actions (e.g. Ctrl-F, Ctrl-S) cannot be canceled" - well as far as I remember, gmail for instance captures Ctrl-S to do a web-based save (rather than the html-file-save) in firefox, all the way back to firefox 3 or even 2, if I remember correctly. No value in 'content safety' but worthwhile for use friendlyness (who pused that key out of editor habbits...)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling hotkeys won't stop anyone from just selecting that option from the File menu.

People will always find ways around these kinds of hacks. Turning off JavaScript, hacking the source with Firebug, Option+Click on a Mac, taking a screenshot, etc. They are completely ineffective against anyone even slightly determined to do what you don't want them to do.

[image]